# Writing big unsigned int64 to mongoDB with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a number I'm getting from an external source I want to write to the mongo as Int

The problem is that the number is above signed Int64 (which is how mongo implements it) - but is still fits unsinged int64

The number is:
9223372036854776000

How can I still write it to mongo?
I'm getting 
`OverflowError: MongoDB can only handle up to 8-byte ints`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest PyMongo and MongoDB 3.4 or later, [you can use the standard Python Decimal with the new BSON Decimal128 type](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/bson/decimal128.html).

```
from decimal import Decimal
from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128
from pymongo import MongoClient

d = Decimal128(Decimal(9223372036854776000))
collection = MongoClient().test.test
collection.insert_one({'myNumber': d})
```

Comment: Cool. Need to update my local mongo to test it. Is there a way to do it in mongo3.2? After all it is not a real 128bit - it is a bitmask causing it to be a big unsigned...

Comment: The Decimal 128 BSON type is not supported in MongoDB 3.2. If you have to use an older version of MongoDB, you could encode the number as a bson.Binary or as a string.