# How to deal with OverflowError: MongoDB can only handle up to 8-byte ints in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using mongoDB for a side-project.
Trying to insert at document using pymongo I get this error:

```
'OverflowError: MongoDB can only handle up to 8-byte ints'
```

The issue is that my document has some `long ints (“value”: 23051923387397964883670) and some small with decimals (“value”: 0.4608369174340644)`.

Does anybody know how to deal with this?

Comment: Similar question maybe some ideas suitable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280033/how-to-handle-long-ints-in-json-while-inserting-into-mongo

Comment: The "value" data, by default, stores in MongoDB as a `double`. In Python its equivalent is a `float`.